# Exception - PlatformException ( java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void td.o.e()' on a null object reference

Tags: flutter, dart, video-player

I'm using video player to play videos in a feed that contains pictures and videos.

For each video in the feed execute the following stateful calls.

Sometimes on Android device I have the following exception for all the videos controllers

What is missing?

Exception:

> PlatformException(java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void td.o.e()' on a null object reference, NullPointerException, Cause: null,
>
> Stacktrace: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void td.o.e()' on a null object reference
>
> at td.s.z(VideoPlayerPlugin.java:2)
> at td.m$a.o(Messages.java:4)
> at td.m$a.I(Unknown Source:0)
> at td.g.a(Unknown Source:2)
> at qc.a$b.a(BasicMessageChannel.java:3)
> at cc.c.l(DartMessenger.java:2)
> at cc.c.m(DartMessenger.java:3)
> at cc.c.i(Unknown Source:0)
> at cc.b.run(Unknown Source:12)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:210)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:299)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8309)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:556)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1038), null)

Code:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:allergy_app/anew/services/posts_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';
import '../../core/presentation/utils/app_constant.dart';
import '../models/post_model.dart';

class VideoPlayerButtonScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const VideoPlayerButtonScreen({super.key, required this.url, required this.keyString, required this.feedModel});
  final String url;
  final String keyString;
  final PostModel feedModel;

  @override
  State<VideoPlayerButtonScreen> createState() => _VideoPlayerButtonScreenState();
}

class _VideoPlayerButtonScreenState extends State<VideoPlayerButtonScreen> {
  VideoPlayerController? _controller;
  Future<void>? _initializeVideoPlayerFuture;
  bool myReaction = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    myReaction = widget.feedModel.myReaction;
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(widget.url);
    if (_controller != null) {
      _initializeVideoPlayerFuture = _controller!.initialize().then((value) {
        if (_controller != null) {
          _controller?.addListener(() {
            if (_controller != null &&
                _controller!.value.isInitialized &&
                !_controller!.value.isPlaying &&
                (_controller!.value.duration == _controller!.value
                    .position)) {
              setState(() {});
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
        splashColor: myReaction ? AppConstant.appBlackColor : AppConstant
            .primaryColor,
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            myReaction = !myReaction;
          });
          PostsService postsService = PostsService();
          postsService.addLikes(
            activityId: widget.feedModel.activityId!, isLike: myReaction,);
          setState(() {});
        },
        child: Container(height: 400.h, width: ((400 * 9 / 16).w),
            child: FutureBuilder(
              future: _initializeVideoPlayerFuture,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                  return Stack(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter, children: <Widget>[
                    ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(13),
                        child:
                        AspectRatio(
                          aspectRatio: 9 / 16, //_controller.value.aspectRatio,
                          child: VideoPlayer(_controller!),
                        )),
                    VideoProgressIndicator(
                      _controller!,
                      allowScrubbing: true,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                          13.w, 3, 13.w, 3),
                      colors: VideoProgressColors(
                          playedColor: Theme
                              .of(context)
                              .primaryColor),
                    ),
                    Container(height: 400.h,
                        width: ((400 * 9 / 16).w),
                        color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0),
                        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                            style: ButtonStyle(
                              backgroundColor: MaterialStateColor
                                  .resolveWith((states) =>
                                  AppConstant.primaryColor
                                      .withOpacity(
                                      1.0),
                              ),
                              shape: MaterialStateProperty
                                  .all<
                                  RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                                RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius
                                      .circular(
                                      18.0),),),
                            ),
                            child: Icon(
                              (_controller != null &&
                                  _controller!.value.isPlaying)
                                  ? Icons.pause
                                  : Icons.play_arrow,
                              color: Colors.black,),
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {
                                if (_controller != null &&
                                    _controller!.value.isPlaying) {
                                  _controller!.pause();
                                } else {
                                  _controller!.play();
                                }
                              });
                            }
                        )
                    ),
                  ]);
                }
                else {
                  return const Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(strokeWidth: 10),
                  );
                }
              },
            )));
  }
}
```

**Flutter doctor**

```
C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat doctor --verbose
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1555], locale he-IL)
    • Flutter version 3.10.2 on channel stable at C:\src\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 9cd3d0d9ff (8 days ago), 2023-05-23 20:57:28 -0700
    • Engine revision 90fa3ae28f
    • Dart version 3.0.2
    • DevTools version 2.23.1

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\merid\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-TiramisuPrivacySandbox, build-tools 33.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio2\jbr\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-9505619)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[X] Visual Studio - develop for Windows
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components

[√] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)

[√] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio2
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-9505619)

[√] VS Code (version 1.78.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\merid\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension can be installed from:
       https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1555]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 112.0.5615.139
    • Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 113.0.1774.57

[√] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
Process finished with exit code 0
```

**pubspec.lock**

```
  video_player:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description:
      name: video_player
      sha256: de95f0e9405f29b5582573d4166132e71f83b3158aac14e8ee5767a54f4f1fbd
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.6.1"
  video_player_android:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: video_player_android
      sha256: ae1c7d9a71c236a1bf9e567bd7ed4c90887e389a5f233b2192593f7f7395005c
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.4.8"
  video_player_avfoundation:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: video_player_avfoundation
      sha256: "4c274e439f349a0ee5cb3c42978393ede173a443b98f50de6ffe6900eaa19216"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.4.6"
  video_player_platform_interface:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: video_player_platform_interface
      sha256: a8c4dcae2a7a6e7cc1d7f9808294d968eca1993af34a98e95b9bdfa959bec684
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "6.1.0"
  video_player_web:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: video_player_web
      sha256: "44ce41424d104dfb7cf6982cc6b84af2b007a24d126406025bf40de5d481c74c"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.0.16"
```